# Yii2 отключить Bootstrap

Tags: yii2, yii

Как в `Yii2` можно полностью отключить подгрузку всех файлов `bootstrap` (`js` и `css`)?

Установил `Basic Template Yii2`, зашел в `AppAsset.php` закомментировал содержимое `$depends`:

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/script.js'
    ];
    public $depends = [
        // 'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        // 'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Но скрипт бутстрапа в конце страницы и `css` в `<head>` все равно подгружаются

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Покопался в коде, пришел к выводу, что если использовать любой виджет `bootstrap4`, бутстрап будет автоматически добавляться на страницу. Из `layout` убрал следующие строки:

```
use app\widgets\Alert;
use yii\bootstrap4\Breadcrumbs;
use yii\bootstrap4\Html;
use yii\bootstrap4\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap4\NavBar;
```

Ну и соответственно убрал из кода использование этих виджетов. И только после этих действий `bootstrap` перестал подгружаться.

Теперь вопрос - как отключить подгрузку всех файлов `bootstrap` (`js` и `css`), **продолжив при этом использовать виджеты** `bootstrap4`? Т.е. Чтобы при написании конструкции вида:

```
<?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
     'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
]) ?>
```

Хлебные крошки создавались, но так как стили и скрипты не подключены, это выглядело как голый `HTML`.
Примерно так должно быть в результате:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли такое реализовать? Если да, то как?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26734385/6104996

Answer (score 0):

1. 'yii\web\YiiAsset' лучше не удалять
2. скорее всего где-то в слоях/страницах(`views`) есть что-то вроде `BootstrapAsset::register($this);`

Answer (score 0):

В conf.php нужно указать, что в bundle ничего не кешировать от bootstrap

```
        'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                    'js'=>[]
                ],
                'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                    'css' => [],
                ],
                ...
                ]
          ...
          ]
```